# Understanding $\forall x$ as for each or for all

Tags: first-order-logic

I find very confusing these different first-order sentences. Can someone confirm on my elaboration or if there is a technique to think about?

> $\forall x \exists y\ x < y$, with domain $\mathbb{N}$ excluding 0 {1,2,3,4..}

For each x there is a y, therefore statement is **true**. However, if I think of $\forall x$ as "for each" I come to the statement above, but if I think of "for all", it goes "for all x exist a y" and this makes me doubt if the statement above is correct, because it sounds like that we want a y for all the x.

I draw here all the possible combinations to make my point clear and I will now just keep going considering $\forall x$ as a "for each".

> $\forall y \exists x\ x < y$

For each y there is a x, therefore it is **false** (e.g x < 1)

> $\exists x \forall y\ x < y$

Exists one x for each y, therefore it is  **false**
 (e.g 1<1)

> $\exists y \forall x\ x < y$

Exists a y for each x, therefore it is **false** (thanks Andres)

Comment: $\forall x$ is often read as "for all $x$." This is perhaps unfortunate, since in ordinary English there may be ambiguity of interpretation which is usually resolved without difficulty from the context. For each $x$ or for any $x$ is more satisfactory, but longer phrases may be better, such as whatever $x$ we are given,  we can "find" a $y$ which may depend on $x$ such that $\dots$.

Comment: The last example you consider is false.

Comment: $\exists y \forall x\ x < y$ is not true. Suppose there did exist some natural number $y=M$ such that $\forall x\ x < M$. What about $x=M+1$?

Comment: You are reading the statements in an *ad hoc* manner, which may contribute to the confusion. For example, the last statement should be read "there is a $y$ such that for all $x$ ..." (or "there exists a $y$ such that for each $x$ ...", if you prefer. What matters here is not "for all" or "for each", but the "such that" following the existential claim. This should make it clear that the same $y$ should work for all possible values of $x$, as opposed to a statement of the form $\forall y\,\exists x\dots$, where we say that no matter what $y$ we consider, we can find an $x$ such that ...

Answer (score 1):

I have often felt this is a problem, both for the ambiguity the "for all"/"for each" that you identify and because at one stage I was in an intuitionistic phase and less confident about making definitive statements about actual infinities.

My suggestions would be

1. Use *"such that"* after *"exists"*: for example your final $\exists y \forall x\ x < y$ would be read as "there exists a $y$ such that for each $x$ it is true that $x \lt y$", which is plainly incorrect for natural numbers, while without it "there exists a $y$ for each $x$ it is true that $x \lt y$" is less clear as to the intended meaning.
2. Prefer *"for each"* (or  André Nicolas's suggestion of *"for any"*) rather than *"for all"*, so that in your initial example $\forall x \exists y\ x < y$ it is more obvious that you are looking at individual values, so this reads as "for each $x$ there exists a $y$ such that it is true that $x \lt y$", which is plainly correct for natural numbers.